# Unable to create layout from MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I m trying to create a layout from MainActivity.java but my emulator is not showing the layout and the button which i have created from MainActivity.java. Do i have to change something in activity_main.xml?
Here is the code,

```
package com.example.pratt.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.graphics.Color;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG="My Message";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*
        */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout myLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        Button blue_button=new Button(this);
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        myLayout.addView(blue_button);
         blue_button.setText("Blue Button");
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
        setContentView(myLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code, but I guess it's because you didn't to add some `LayoutParams` for your layout, for example, your layout's width and height. If you don't want to use fixed width and height you can use `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTNT` or `MATCH_PARENT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should create the `Button` before `@Override`.

```
private static final String TAG="My Message";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*
        */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout myLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Button blue_button=new Button(this);
        blue_button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,       
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        myLayout.addView(blue_button);
        blue_button.setText("Blue Button");
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
        setContentView(myLayout);
    }
```

You have not specified the dimensions of the `button`. Hence, it creates a button of `0dp x 0dp`.

Hope this helps !